# How can I apportion a total by percentages where each cell is an integer and they sum to exactly the original total?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

```
      Date
Nov-11     Dec-11
50         102

   Percent
0          0
0          34
34         33
33         33
33         0

  Apportion
0          0
0          35
17         34
16         34
16         0

     Sum
49         103
```

The 5 percentages of the first column correspond to splitting up the 50 above into integer parts in the 5 cells under the apportion header. The results in there have come from a simple Round(x*%,0). I want all of the values below to sum to the 50 exactly in the first column. This can be accomplished by altering any number of non-zero values in the Apportion section.

If it's possible to do this with formulas I haven't been able to figure out how. Every thing I try is a circular reference. The problem is that any of the percentages can be 0 so I can't just create a bucket one that accounts for the under/overflow.

Please let me know if more information is needed. This is the first time I've asked a question ever on SO. I can't attach a picture, so I've attempted to draw the table above with code.

Comment: Clearly Rounding is the cause of the sum 'error'.  To adjust the sum to 100 will require modifying one or more of the rounded results, you need to tell us what the expected result is.

Comment: Instead of rounding the calculation why not display as an integer.  That way, the amounts will be 17, 16.5 and 16.5 but will display as 17, 16 and 16 and so will sum to 50.

Comment: @chrisneilsen: Sorry if I wasn't more clear. I understand rounding is the issue. I'm wondering if there's a more clever way to do it so that the totals will sum to the original number. The reason to problem is hard is because the percentages can vary and be 0.

Comment: @TonyDallimore: The actual final results need to be integers that sum to the original integer because they're inputs for something else.

Comment: Like I said, to adjust the sum to 100 will require modifying one or more of the rounded results.  This can be done in many ways.  You need to tell us what the expected result is: for the examples given in the OP add a column showing what you would _like_ the results to be.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Any result where they are integers that always sum to the integer under the date at the top is acceptable. The reason I'm finding this difficult is because I can't bucket the accumulated variance into one of the totals because any of that totals could have the requirement of being 0.

Comment: Are you saying it's Ok to adjust any _one_ of the results, even if that result would otherwise be `0`?

Comment: @chrisneilsen It's ok to adjust any result(s) unless that result is 0. I'm assuming a solution where one is adjusted would be simpler though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that will adjust the aportionment for the *last* non-zero percentage.

Based on data layout as follows:
Taget sum in `A1`
Percentages in `A5:A9`
One Cell after the Percent range must be blank (`A10`)
Apportion in `A12:A16`

Formula for Aportionment range (for cell `A12`, then copy down.  Can be copied across as well)

```
=IF(AND(SUM(A6:A$10)=0,A5>0),A$2-SUM(A$11:A11),ROUND(A$2*(A5%),0))
```

How it works:

1. the `IF(AND(...` determines if the cell is the last non-zero percentage by summing the percentages below the current one.  The `Sum` range extends one cell beyond the Percent range to make it work for the last row.
2. If the `IF` is true, calculate the approtionment as `Target - Sum(Rows Above)`.  The `Sum` range extends one cell above the Percent range to make it work for the first row.
3. If the `IF` is false, calculate the apportionment as a rounded percentage

Comment: I ended up using your solution because it felt cleaner than the other one provided and it integrated better with the logic I already had in place. I tried to vote you up but I only have 11 reputation so I can't. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a different way of achieving your objective.

This shows the appearance of the worksheet except (1) Columns B and D would be hidden and (2) values would not be left justified as I have shown them.

```
     |A         |B         |C         |D         |
 1   |Date      |          |          |          |
 2   |Nov-11    |          |Dec-11    |          |
 3   |50        |          |102       |          |
 4   |          |          |          |          |
 5   |Percent   |          |Percent   |          |
 6   |0         |          |0         |          |
 7   |0         |          |34        |          |
 8   |34        |          |33        |          |
 9   |33        |          |33        |          |
10   |33        |          |0         |          |
11   |          |          |          |          |
12   |Apportion |          |Apportion |          | 
13   |0         |0.00      |0         |0.00      |
14   |0         |0.00      |35        |0.32      |
15   |17        |0.00      |33        |-0.66     |
16   |17        |0.50      |34        |0.34      |
17   |16        |          |0         |          |
18   |          |          |          |          |
19   |Sum       |          |Sum       |          |
20   |          |          |          |          |
21   |50        |          |102       |          |
```

The following cells contain the formulae shown:

```
A13  =ROUND(IF(A6=0,0,A$3*A6/100)-B12,0)
A14  =ROUND(IF(A7=0,0,A$3*A7/100)-B13,0)
A15  =ROUND(IF(A8=0,0,A$3*A8/100)-B14,0)
A16  =ROUND(IF(A9=0,0,A$3*A9/100)-B15,0)
A17  =ROUND(IF(A10=0,0,A$3*A10/100)-B16,0)
A21  =SUM(A13:A17)
B13  =A13-IF(A6=0,0,A$3*A6/100)
B14  =A14-IF(A7=0,0,A$3*A7/100)
B15  =A15-IF(A8=0,0,A$3*A8/100)
B16  =A16-IF(A9=0,0,A$3*A9/100)
```

The formulae must be typed into A13 and B13 and then copied down.  Note B17 does not need a formula but B17 is not referenced so it would not matter if it had a formula.

Copy A13:B17 to C13:D17

B13 contains the amount that has been added to A13 to make it an integer.  B13 is subtracted from A14 before A14 is rounded.  And so on down the column.  The result is that all the roundings are used up in later rows.

I have used this technique before and my client was happy with the result.  You will not get much better than this without using VBA.